# Create file path and filename in JSON and send it to Discord

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been working on a function which I call `report`. What it does is that whenever I call the `report` function. I can give it a payload of my dict with some data and as well as `reason` where I can have custom message or the exception errors of whatever can happened.

For now I have created something simple where I create names for `file_path` and `filename`. I check if there is a path for that name already and if not then we create. We create a JSON file with the report data to my local PC and then I send it to discord. Both the JSON file and a small text that describes that there has been and error and to check it out ASAP.

My question here is pretty simple to see if there is anything I can actually improve my code somehow. Make it less code or a better report, I take whatever possible!

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import json
import os
import time
from datetime import datetime
from typing import List

from discord_webhook import DiscordEmbed, DiscordWebhook


# payload example payload = {"store": "burger-king"}
# reason = Custom message or exception err

def report(payload=None, reason=None):

    webhook = DiscordWebhook(
        url="https://discord....."
    )

    embed = DiscordEmbed(title="An error has occurred", color=16711680)

    # -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Create file path and filename
    # -------------------------------------------------------------------------

    file_path = f'./error/{payload["store"] if payload else "Other"}'
    filename = f'{datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), "%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S-%f")}.json'

    # Check if the path already exists
    if not os.path.exists(file_path):
        os.makedirs(file_path)

    # Write to a JSON file
    with open(f"{file_path}/{filename}", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        f.write(json.dumps(
            {
                "payload": payload if payload else None,
                "reason": str(reason)
            },
            indent=4,
            ensure_ascii=False
        ))
    
    # -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Filename embed
    # -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    embed.add_embed_field(name="Filename", value=filename, inline=False)

    # -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Send files to discord
    # -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    with open(f"{file_path}/{filename}", "rb") as f:
        webhook.add_file(file=f.read(), filename=f"{filename}")

    # -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Footer timestamp
    # -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    embed.set_footer(text=f'AutoSnkr | {datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d [%H:%M:%S.%f")[:-3]}]')

    webhook.add_embed(embed)

    # -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Send to discord with exceptions
    # -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    while True:

        response = webhook.execute()
        
        # Workaround bug from discord_webhook pypi
        if isinstance(response, List):
            assert (len(response) == 1)
            response = response[0]
            
        # Successful requests
        if response.ok:
            return
        
        # Rate limit. Wait until the limitation is gone
        elif response.status_code == 429:
            sleep_time = int(response.headers["retry-after"]) / 1000
            time.sleep(sleep_time)

        else:
            print("Big error here! This text needs to be replaced later on")
            return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- There's comments above `report` which should really be a docstring,
  since they explain the function's workings.
- The default parameters for `report` are a bit suspect:

  - The expression `payload if payload else None` is redundant, can just
    be `payload` then.
  - `str(reason)` for the default value `None` for `reason` is odd,
    maybe that also needs special casing and could be left out of the
    JSON body?
- Does the value from `payload["store"]` need escaping / is it safe?
  E.g. if it's coming from the server you'd have to validate it before
  using it as part of a filename to prevent attacks.
- I feel it's a bit over-commented.  Consider "Create file path and
  filename" - that's basically what I can discern from the block below,
  same as "Check if the path already exists", that's basically the same
  as the line `if not os.path.exists(file_path)`.  Consider splitting
  off smaller functions that have descriptive names instead of one huge
  function, that way you wouldn't have to comment on blocks of code (and
  would instead use the function names as descriptors).
- `with` is used, good.
- `os.makedirs` won't do anything if the path already exists, so the
  check before it is redundant.
- Consider making `webhook` and `embed` (global) constants, they
  otherwise don't seem to add anything to the function.
- After writing the JSON to the file, it's immediately being read back
  for the `webhook.add_file` - avoid that unnecessary computation and
  reuse the in-memory representation of the data.
- Again, consider splitting the setup phase and the `while True` loop
  into separate functions to help understanding and, potentially,
  testability.
- The only thing I'd have to complain about in the loop is the fetching
  of the retry timeout value: Be conservative in what you expect.  The
  server doesn't *have* to send that value and if it doesn't you'll get
  exceptions.  Consider providing a default value and a maximum sleep
  amount to not open yourself up to a malicious server (yes, that's a
  stretch, but still).
- Just noticed:  You're importing `typing.List` just to check
  `isinstance` - AFAIK you can just use `isinstance(response, list)`
  without the need to import the `typing` module.  Of course using
  `typing` is great, you'd just have annotate your functions most likely
  and use `mypy` or a similar type-checker ...

Comment: Appreciate the beautiful code review! There was alot of new stuff I wouldn't think of and will of course add it to my code! Thank you so much for it!